# videoJS player free or paid software

Tags: video.js

We have a commercial Product which we sell it to our clients. Can i use this player for free in my product? Are there any license restrictions. Even if you don't have restrictions,play video in web through rtmp streaming. Does it have any restrictions?

Thanks
jc

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the video.js GitHub page it says

> Video.js is licensed under the [Apache License, Version 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

After <s>reviewing the license</s> skimming this page at [tldrlegal](https://tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-(apache-2.0)).  Yes you can use the player for free as long as you include the original copyright, license, and notice.